# Precompiling rails-3 assets pipeline, makes javascript failing, preventing heroku deploy

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, asset-pipeline

I use [datatables](http://datatables.net/) js on rails-3.2.3/bootstrap application, to sort table's fields.

If I run the app locally without precopiling assets pipeline, it works fine but, as soon I run :

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

the resulting public/assets prevent DataTables plug-in to work, even if it appear correctly packaged into public/assets/manifest.yml file and public/assets directory :

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$ ls -l app/assets/javascripts
total 84
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave   553 2012-04-27 21:36 application.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave    99 2012-04-20 21:37 bootstrap.js.coffee
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave  3387 2012-04-26 20:12 DT_bootstrap.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave 71947 2012-04-26 20:12 jquery.dataTables.min.js
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$
```

either application.js looks right :

```
app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require DT_bootstrap
//= require jquery.dataTables.min
//= require_tree .
```

Of course this is even more problematic because it prevent rails app to work on heroku ( I can compile the app from scratch, or use the locally precompiled version, but they don't work anyway ).

How can I do ?

Comment: Why do you call `//= require_tree ` after manually including all files?

Comment: ... no you don't, I erroneusly forgot it there after one of the try. Anyway it doesn't stop anything for sure ... after removing that, the pipeline still breaks DataTables js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just got it working myself. Are you using the `jquery-datatables-rails` gem? If not, you should! Put this line in your gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
```

and run:

> bundle install

NOTE: Don't put it in your assets group or it will not work when deploying to heroku (since the assets group is not used in production).

Also, make sure to put this line in your application.rb:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Add these to your application.js

```
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
```

Add this to your application.css:

```
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
```

And add this to your js.coffee file for your controller you are using datatables in:

If you are using fluid containers:

```
#// For fluid containers
$('#dashboard').dataTable({
  "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
  "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"
});
```

If you are using fixed width containers:

```
#// For fixed width containers
$('.datatable').dataTable({
  "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
  "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"
});
```

Comment: PS: This method lets you deploy to heroku without having to first precompile assets locally.  I find precompiling assets locally to be messy.

Comment: we have 2 jquery-datatables-rails gems, one is https://github.com/kclair/jquery-datatables-rails the other is https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails Which one did you use ?

Comment: github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails

Comment: Thanks Luca for asking -- I updated the answer above to include putting this line in the gemfile:
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'

Comment: Great Tips here Ira, it works fine. I don't know how to thank you !

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few reasons this doesn't work. Best bet is start here:

http://www.neilmiddleton.com/heroku-asset-pipeline-faq/

Comment: Yes, already done. I tried the differents way mentioned but this breack the assets pipeline locally, on my machine too, even before deploy.